# How to toggle "Magnify with button" quickly, maybe with Tasker?

Tags: tasker, accessibility, intents

I often want to use "Magnify with button" (Android 8 > Settings > Accessibility > Magnification).

Unfortunately, it interferes with the keyboard chooser (Settings > System > Languages > Virtual keyboard > Gboard > Advanced > Show app icon), which I use frequently.

So, I want a quick way to toggle "Magnify with button", preferably from the notification area.

My guess — I'm no expert, so I could be wrong — is that I can use an "intent" to toggle the setting. I could do this from Tasker (maybe you know a better way?).

My problem is that despite plenty of searching, I cannot find the intent setting, or indeed any other way to achieve this.

If "Magnify with button" cannot be easily toggled, but "Magnify with triple-tap" can, that would be an acceptable compromise. (I don't want to leave "Magnify with triple-tap" on permanently because it interferes with normal access.)

Are you able to help, please? My phone is **not** rooted, and rooting isn't an option for me.